# Access Specifier check for virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, access-specifier

```
class Base{
    public:
    virtual void func()
    {
        cout<< "base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base{
    private:
    void func(){
        cout<< "derived";
    }
};

int main() {
    Base *b = new Derived();
    b->func(); //output  = "derived"
    return 0;
}
```

When overloading the base function on creation of derived class    virtual function , shouldn't vtable also take in the access specifier of the derived class?(for me it seems to be against c++ principles) . 
Please also explain the decision why the base class access specifier is followed.

Comment: Access specifiers in C++ aren't what most people think they are. So it's not "against C++ principles". It may be against principles of other languages (drawing a blank here, however), but C++ is not those languages.

Comment: Could you please clarify how "Access specifiers in C++ aren't what most people think they are. " ?

Comment: They don't affect name visibility. They only affect in which scopes a name can be used. It's not uncommon for the unaware to be stumped when, say, overload resolution picks a private overload. They expect the name to not be there. But it is.